# Angular ngrx - and Router.Events inside Rxjs combineLatest doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, ngrx

I'm in trouble with an issue that I can't solve:

```
onSelectCompany() {
 combineLatest([this.idCompany$, this.idUser$, this.router.events]).subscribe(res => {
   if(res[2] instanceOf NavigationEnd){
     this.router.navigateByUrl(`get-info/${res[0]/res[1]`)
   }
 })
}
```

and I call this function on ngOnInit of my component, I have two observables that I need like parameters to my url and I need to navigate on this url only if I have not refreshed the page. But the function that I write doesn't work, I have no error but in debug the execution doesn't go into the subscribtion. Why?

Comment: all 3 must emit something after that function is executed

Comment: instead no, if I remove this.router.events it works...the problem is the router.events observable...I can't understand why

Comment: yes because the router.events will only emit something when there's a routing event

Comment: so, I can't use the combineLatest in this case

Comment: I updated my answer with a "solution"

Comment: Did it work or not?

Answer (score 0):

All 3 observables must emit something after that function is executed.

Source: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest

```
Be aware that combineLatest will not emit an initial value 
until each observable emits at least one value.
```

1 solution could be to move the function from `ngOnInit` to the field level or to the constructor

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe bypass it by using `startWith` operator to simulate the router event. And it would be also easier for you if you destructure on the `combineLatest` result, instead of accessing it using indexes.

```
onSelectCompany() {
 const helper$ = this.router.events.pipe(startWith(null)); // or some other 'safe' value
 combineLatest([this.idCompany$, this.idUser$, helper$])
 .subscribe(([ companyId, userId, routerEvent ]) => {
 // destructure the res array and access the values with variable names
   if(routerEvent instanceOf NavigationEnd){
     this.router.navigateByUrl(`get-info/${companyId}/${userId}`)
   }
 })
}
```